# compiling C++ code with intel compiler on Mac error: expected an identifier

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, compilation, intel

My laptop can not compile a simple c++ code since yesterday, it works perfectly fine before.

The c++ code is can be a hello-world code in main.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile the code by

```
icpc main.cpp
```

The error information is

In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm(637),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__string(56),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view(171),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string(470),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale(15),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ios(216),
                 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream(38),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits(2065): error: expected an identifier
      : public decltype((_VSTD::__is_assignable_test<_Tp, _Arg>(0))) {};

compilation aborted for main.cpp (code 2)

A few information:

- I am using icpc (ICC) 17.0.4 20170411, it is installed from Intel® Parallel Studio XE Composer Edition for C++ macOS.
- My mac is MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017), version 10.12.6.
- If I use gnu compiler, it works fine. While my code needs to use intel's compiler.
- The code works before, do not know while it becomes this. I have already tried restarting the systems.

======================================================================
**Update1**: The problem happened after I update my "Command Line Tools for Xcode". It looks like the `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/` is not right.

======================================================================
**Update2**: This is can be solved by using `icpc -std=c++11 main.cpp`

However when I change my main.cpp to

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

tuple<vector<int>, vector<int>, vector<int>> 
getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple(const vector<int> &vec)
{
    vector<int> fact, mean, err;
    fact.resize( vec.size() );
    mean.resize( vec.size() );
    err.resize(  vec.size() );
    return make_tuple(fact, mean, err);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

It has error again even if I use `icpc -std=c++11 main.cpp`

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__tuple(401): error: type name is not allowed
  -> __all<typename enable_if<_Trait<_LArgs, _RArgs>::value, bool>::type{true}...>;

      detected during:
```

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to compile this as C++, rather than C? If you've accidentally set your compiler to "compile as C" in the "choose language", that would explain it. Or you've made updates to the C++ headers on your system, and they are no longer compatible with your actual compiler (e.g. C++14 instead of C++11)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: `icpc` is the C++ compiler.  Without a `-xc` argument, it should be comiling as C++.  Maybe the OP needs `-std=gnu++14` or something; since they seem to be using `icpc` with the system C++ headers.  Or maybe icpc just won't accept `decltype`, but clang will.  (I didn't think gcc would, though)

Comment: Try adding -std=c++11 to the flags.

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions. -std=c++11 flags works. However, when I try to use tuple, it has the same problem. Why my intel compiler is trying to include the /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/ header, can I include other header of intel c++?

Comment: I update the problem and error message above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue while upgrading command line tools to the version of September 2017

While not finding a proper solution, I reinstalled previous version ( April 2017) of command line tools and it solved the problem (https://developer.apple.com/download/more/#).

I am looking forward to having a clean solution.

EDIT (5/12/17):
I solved the issue by recompiling everything using gcc. At compilation, Intel compilers will use the compiler that responds to `gcc` and `g++` in the path. An installation with homebrew and some symlink in `/usr/local/bin` pushes the newly installed `gcc` in front of clang and then avoids gcc to change at each system update. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that you are using right settings 
and GNU is working because it automatically set to C++
try to set compiler to c++
hope this works.
OR You can use xcode to write c++ Code.

Comment: Thank you, Zain. I can compile with gnu. How do you recommend to check my setting?